# Create custom styling in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm about to start a new project in Xamarin, since we need to create a mobile app for Android and iOS. But we require that both platforms look exactly the same.

Is it possible to do this using Xamarin or is it only possible using something like Cordova?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/

Answer (score 1):

> **require that both platforms look exactly the same**

It depends upon what you mean by that statement.

In regards to `Xamarin.Forms`, "native" widgets are used on each platform so the "same" app's UI, deployed to a different platform, will look different (the difference can be slight or vary greatly based upon the controls used).

Web based / Hybrid apps tend to render fairly the same on each platform. Each platform does have its own HTML/CSS rendering engine so there are differences, and thus the CSS can vary from platform to platform to obtain the desired "sameness".

There are GUI frameworks that render their own controls/widgets and do not use the platform "native" ones. While a lot of these tend to be game related UI frameworks, there are many options available depending upon want you requirements are.

i.e.

- OmniGUI : A Xamarin.Forms friendly cross-platform that renders its own controls and thus looks the same on each platform.
- Flutter : Google's mobile UI framework that renders its own "widgets". While there are widget collections that have Material Design and Cupertino styles applied, you can use the basic widgets and style them in a "CSS" like analog using Google's Dartlanguage.
- Many others...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Can you mention other frameworks we can use to unify the Xamarin UI?