# How to create same UI as given UX in xamarin forms?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, user-experience

I am working in xamarin forms. I have some UX given by the designer. Now I want to create exactly same UI(same height of control, width of control, colors etc) in xamarin forms. My xaml view should be exactly xame like given UX.

Is there any tool that can guide me to create same UI like UX. I mean through that tool I can get the height, widths and colors of controls of screens and then can use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113136/create-custom-styling-in-xamarin/49116489#49116489

Answer (score 2):

it's not good idea to use exact length of UI since the app will run on different screen and different devices. Xamarin forms uses native views for each platform which will also change the look of basic views.

What you need to do is to use grids or other layouts for sizing and control the height and the width of your views.

I also suggested that you always use scroll view incase if a mobile has a small screen size.

Finally, regarding the actual UI components and UX interactions, there are many ready components like calendars, custom checkboxes, sliders,... . If you can't find a component that cover what you need, you have 2 options:

- combine different components and try to customize them with absolute
  and Relative layouts.
- Create the components yourself which will    require some knowledge
  on each platform to create the view component    by drawing it and do
  all the handling for each platform.

Regarding the UX, there are many libraries for animations and most components allow customizability.

Your question was very general so this answer is general. Please try to be more specific next time.